# Error CS0177: "Debug" does not contain a definition for "DrawLine"

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am writing a script for an fps assault rifle. I am getting this error: "Error CS0177: "Debug" does not contain a definition for "DrawLine." "
I am not able to fix this bug, can anyone help?

The script is shown below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class weaponController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float fireRate = 20f;

    public GameObject cameraGameObject;

    private void FixedUpdate() {

        if(Input.GetKeyDown("fire1")){
            fire();
        }
    }
    private void fire(){
        RaycastHit hit;

        if(Physics.Raycast(cameraGameObject.transform.position,cameraGameObject.transform.forward,out hit)){
            Debug.Drawline(transform.position,hit.pos);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write `DrawLine`. Not `Drawline`. C# is case sensitive. This means that `DrawLine` and `Drawline` are different functions. Change your script to this:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class weaponController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float fireRate = 20f;

    public GameObject cameraGameObject;

    private void FixedUpdate() {

        if(Input.GetKeyDown("fire1")){
            fire();
        }
    }
    private void fire(){
        RaycastHit hit;

        if(Physics.Raycast(cameraGameObject.transform.position,cameraGameObject.transform.forward,out hit)){
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position,hit.point);
        }
    }
}
```

Check one of the last lines. I change the ‘l’ to ‘L’.

And for your particle effect:

```cs
public ParticleSystem ps;

void Update()
{
   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
   {
       flash.Play();
   }
}
```

(Make sure that the particle has ‘play on awake’ set to false.) The particle system into the slot in the inspector called ‘ps’. Make sure that the particle system is childed to the player if you want the particle system to be right next to your player.

And this is another particle system that you could use if you want. This one is better than the last one, because it instantiates the particle system instead of just playing it.

```cs
GameObject ps;

void Update()
{
   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
   {
      Instantiate(ps, transform.position);
   }
}
```

Drag the particle system into the ps slot. This time it is a game object, because we can Instantiate game objects. In your particle system settings of the flash, activate play on awake. Then add a script to this particle system that is set to this:

```
void Start()
{
   Destroy(gameObject, 1f);
}
```

Where the second variable is the amount of seconds until you want to destroy the particle system.

Comment: Yes, I have another question, It says "Error CS1061: "RaycastHit" does not contain a definition for "pos" and no accessible extension method "pos" accepting a first argument" can you help me with that too? btw, thanks for the previous comment.

Comment: Oh yes, there is no ‘pos’ in RaycastHit, so I assume you mean the position of where the raycast hit?

Comment: I changed the line of code with the new error to draw a line from the player to the hit of the raycast. The correct variable for this is ‘point’ instead of ‘pos’.

Comment: alright @ken, thanks so much for your help, btw, are you the one who has helped me before bro, just curious.

Comment: @RenzocFN What do you mean? Helped you where? Do you mean that I helped you on a question before here, because I can’t remember and I checked your profile, and you haven’t asked questions here before.

Comment: do you know the correct variable to play a particle effect bro.

Comment: I have asked a question before and thought that you helped me before on stack overflow.

Comment: @RenzocFN I checked your profile and you must have deleted your old question or were on a different account, but it is possible. And you said that you want to know how to play a particle effect. I can write something short if that’s what you meant.

Comment: yes, please, here is the line that I wrote " flash.play(); "

Comment: Ok, it took a while, but I added it to the original answer. I am going away now, so I can’t fix any bugs and I will be back in about an hour, so here is a [link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/551466/how-play-and-stop-a-particlesystem-through-scripti.html) about this topic.